# Spring Cloud Ribbon Consul Load balancing timeout

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I have a spring boot application autodiscovering in `Consul` a downstream microservice by his serviceId.

**Problem:**
For some reasons some of previous registered services in `Consul` (which are not running anymore) are still returned during discovery.

So if I'm lucky load balancing is working through my `restTemplate` but sometimes I've a timeout because non running services are returned.

**Questions on best practices to handle this use case:**

- Is it possible to log the host/service in error and not just timeout?

error:
`a resourceAccessException I/O error on GET request for http://SERVICE-NAME .... connection timeout`

- Is it possible to log through the restTemplate the node chosen when loadbalancing occured ?

Does this kind of logging makes sense or is it better to let the magic happen later on, when Circuit breaker is implemented ?

thanks!

Comment: You can not prevent timeouts. The service can die the same moment consul returns it to you. You'd need to be able to predict the future to solve that problem. Strategies like making multiple requests and taking the fastest response are used in some cases to deal with that. The only solution is to make your service client code smarter (or to move that logic  into a dedicated rpc layer)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! but how to log which one is failing ? I'm using restTemplate for convenience but I didn't see a way to log who I'm querying.

Comment: @landbit, we could look at the logging and see if we could help there. Can you create an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues

Comment: @specergibb thanks for your answer, I don't know what to think... Will this add any value to log this event in the end? isn't implementing circuit breaker pattern with hystrix/turbine dashboard enough to monitor the state of all microservices?